# How to add initial data to angularjs app from rendered html

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm creating a large AngularJs App, which requires **User Login**.
After *authenticating* user, a page is rendered to him and subsequent data is loaded later.

There are two ways for this:

- **XHR Fetch after Page Load**:
  This means sending an XHR request in 'run' block or somewhere to get *LoggedIn* user. say to `'/api/current_user.json'`
- **Data Embedded in HTML**
  To avoid initial load time of above method, I think its good to embed some `JSON` in Html page as a `<script>` tag.

However, I'm unable to get this data in 'script' tag from my `module.run` block.
How can I do that ?

Comment: .constant('user',myGlobalUser) take a look on how this topic is managed by mean.io folks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `window object` or use `ng-init` to pass the data from the rendered HTML to Angular:

**Window Object**

Assign your values to the "window" object. In Angular inject the $window service which references the window object and access your stored values.

Example:

In your HTML file:

```
<script>
  window.init = { name: "John Doe" };
</script>
```

In the controller (should work similarly for the run block):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {      
  $scope.user = $window.init;
  ...
}]);
```

**Ng-Init**

Create a function that initializes the values for you.

In the HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="initialize( { name: 'Jane Doe' } )">
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.initialize = function( json ) {
  $scope.user2 = json;
};
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UIrQ1sew8cx9syuMg53D?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @andrbmgi, but i prefer not to pollute global window object, is there some other way than this or this may be only one?

Comment: Point taken. You could always do `delete $window.init;` to unpolute ;). I updated the plnkr.

Comment: I included another option going with ng-init. This polutes your $scope with another function. A fix for that... you guessed `delete $scope.initialize`. The plnkr now contains both soultions side by side.